# Scrapy: FormRequest doesn't auto-populate ASP.net hidden fields

Tags: python, html, forms, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to scrape some gold that's behind an authentication screen. The website uses `ASP.net` and ASP's got some stupid hidden fields littered all over the form (like `__VIEWSTATE`, `__EVENTTARGET`).

When I call `FormRequest.from_response(response,...` I'm expecting that it reads these hidden fields automatically from the response and populates them in the `formdata` dictionary - which is what [Scrapy's FormRequest](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response) documentation says it *should* do.

But if that's the case, then why does the login process only work when I explicitly list these fields and populate them?

```
class ItsyBitsy(Spider):
    name = "itsybitsy"
    allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://website.com/cpanel/Default.aspx"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Performs authentication to get past the login form
        sel = Selector(response)
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
        formdata={
        'tb_Username':'admin',
        'tb_Password':'password',

        # The following fields should be auto populated, right?
        # So why does removing 'em break the login (w/500 Server Error)
        '__VIEWSTATE':
              sel.xpath("//input[@name='__VIEWSTATE']/@value").extract(),
        '__EVENTVALIDATION':
              sel.xpath("//input[@name='__EVENTVALIDATION']/@value").extract(),
        '__EVENTTARGET': 'b_Login'

        },
        callback=self.after_login,
        clickdata={'id':'b_Login'},
        dont_click=True)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # Mmm, scrumptious
        pass
```

### Edit: Adding form HTML

```
<form id="form1" action="Default.aspx" method="post" name="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" value="" id="__EVENTTARGET" name="__EVENTTARGET">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" name="__EVENTARGUMENT">
<input type="hidden" value="/wEPDwULLTE2OTg2NjA1NTAPZBYCAgMPZBYGAgMPD2QWAh4Kb25rZXlwcmVzcwUlcmV0dXJuIGNsaWNrQnV0dG9uKGV2ZW50LCAnYl9Mb2dpbicpO2QCBQ8PZBYCHwAFJXJldHVybiBjbGlja0J1dHRvbihldmVudCwgJ2JfTG9naW4nKTtkAgcPD2QWAh4Hb25jbGljawUPcmV0dXJuIGxvZ2luKCk7ZGRKt/WTOQThVTxB9Y0QcIuRqylCIw==" id="__VIEWSTATE" name="__VIEWSTATE">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//&lt;![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]&gt;
</script>


<div>

<input type="hidden" value="/wEWBAK0o8DDCQLxz5rcDwLF8dCIDALHyYWSA+rA4VJNaEpFIycMDHQPUOz393TI" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" name="__EVENTVALIDATION">
<input type="text" onkeypress="return clickButton(event, 'b_Login');" size="28" class="textfield-text" id="tb_Username" name="tb_Username">
<input type="password" onkeypress="return clickButton(event, 'b_Login');" size="28" class="textfield-text" id="tb_Password" name="tb_Password">
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('b_Login','')" class="button-link" id="b_Login" onclick="return login();">Login</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Please show the contents of the `form` tag where the inputs are.

Comment: @alecxe done. Shouldn't make much of a difference since i'm clearly able to retrieve it using XPATH right?

Comment: I guess there are multiple forms. Can you add `'formname':'form1'` to the formdata dictionary for a test?

Comment: @sp1der it doesn't work as expected. When requesting the next page after authentication, I get a `302` back to the login page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/request/form.py#L90), `Scrapy` uses the following CSS selector to parse the inputs out of the form:

```
descendant::textarea|descendant::select|descendant::input[@type!="submit" and @type!="image" and @type!="reset"and ((@type!="checkbox" and @type!="radio") or @checked)]
```

In other words, all of your hidden inputs are successfully parsed (and sent with the request later) with the values equal to `value` attributes. So, Scrapy does what it should here.

The login using `from_response()` doesn't work because `__EVENTTARGET` has a empty `value` attribute.  If you make the login using a real browser, `__EVENTTARGET` parameter value would be set to `b_Login` via javascript `__doPostBack()` function call. And, since Scrapy cannot handle javascript (cannot call js functions), `__EVENTTARGET` is sent with an empty value which causes login failure.

`__EVENTARGUMENT` has an empty `value` too, but it is actually set to the empty string in the `__doPostBack()` function, so it doesn't make a difference here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Just one question though - if that were the case, why does the XPATH statement correctly retrieve the hidden fields (if they're being populated via Javascript, and Scrapy doesn't execute javascript functions)?

Comment: @FloatingRock sure, every field except `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` has a non-empty `value `attribute. `__EVENTARGUMENT` is not relevant since it's always empty. `__EVENTTARGET` value you have to set set manually to `b_login`. Hope this makes sense yo you.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I just need to manually set `__EVENTTARGET` and everything else does in fact get filled by Scrapy. Tested it, and it worked! Thanks!!

Comment: When ASP.NET uses AJAX, it passes __EVENTRARGET and other such arguments in a pipe-delimited format. Scrapy is not equipped to capture these changes and hence fails in that case.